# Unload a minifilter driver with no unload routine?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, minifilter

This is probably a pretty easy question to answer for someone that is experienced with FS minifilters. I am trying to script the removal of a filter driver and device.

Some background... this driver is running on Windows 8/10 x64. The vendor that created the driver has not been helpful in fulfilling my request for a removal tool. Unfortunately their MSI uninstall is buggy and only works about half the time you run it... They want us to upgrade to their newest version that doesn't have the bug we are encountering during uninstallation. We aren't interested in continuing use of this software so a paid upgrade seems frivolous... Their only suggestion has been to reimage the computers without the software that includes the FS minifilter device... That's out of the questions because it is on 1000+ computers...

Basically, their official uninstaller does an API callback to one of their servers and verifies the machines eligibility to uninstall:

1. Does the MAC address of the primary network adapter exist in their
   database?
2. Does the password you entered for uninstallation match
   what is set in their database?

If you are eligible, it runs an MSI uninstallation and disables the FS filter, removes the driver file, service files, configuration, and restarts... The bug that is keeping us from doing a normal bulk removal (their way) is that the MSI freezes during the removal process (after checking eligibility) and requires us to restart a client computer up to 3 times to finish the uninstall.

I have been able to successfully remove the software and device/driver by externally mounting the Windows file system and manually removing the driver file under System32/Drivers and also removing all of the actual program files/services.  I have not been able to do this booted onto the same partition where the minifilter is loaded. The minifilter driver that is running is protecting those program files, a registry key, and the actual .sys file under System32...

I've done some basic reverse engineering of their MSI... They are using custom actions to perform the removal... First step is the removal of the service, second step is the removal of the minifilter. Both actions are done via an executable that is packaged in the MSI... I've extracted that and attempted to use it by running the same commands that they do during the MSI... I haven't had any luck. The minifilter just doesn't want to die.

They have some other custom actions that are loaded via DLL. Initial investigation makes me think its all of their custom uninstall eligibility craziness.

It looks like their minifilter doesn't have an unload routine built in. Using FLTMC I get this error attempting to detach and/or unload:

```
0x801f0010 Do not detach the filter from the volume at this time.
0x801f0014 Do not detach the filter from the volume at this time.
```

Does anyone know of a good way to unload a minifilter that is throwing those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are desperate enough, look into Windows PE, available as part of the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit.

A Windows PE image can be remotely installed onto a machine's hard disk and configured to perform whatever task you need done and then automatically reboot back into the original operating system.  Doing it this way gives you the same access as externally mounting the infected file system, but can be automated.  I've used this approach in the past to automate offline maintenance tasks on several hundred machines (e.g., changing a registry setting that Symantec Endpoint Protection was "protecting") and while getting it working is fiddly, once it *is* working it works well.

---

*My email address is in my profile, you're welcome to contact me if you decide on this approach and have questions about implementing it.*

*Alternatively, depending on your jurisdiction and circumstances, you might want to consider threatening the vendor with a lawsuit if they refuse to provide a proper solution.  They broke your computers, it should be their job to fix it.  From the sounds of it, they wouldn't even need to do any work, just let you have the upgraded version for a few weeks free of charge.*

Comment: Thank you, Harry. I appreciate your kind offer to help with the WinPE uninstall. I was actually able to find a command that the vendor runs during the MSI uninstall that works to unload the minifilter driver. I was able to come up with a proof of concept that unloads and removes all relevant files/registry keys upon reboot. It seems to be working well so that will probably be the direction I move. I am also considering sharing this with the vendor and see if they would like to do it in a more official way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try to kick out FltMgr.sys of the kernel by:

1. Renaming %SystemRoot%\sytem32\drivers\FltMgr.sys
2. Or changing HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\FltMgr\Type to 0x4 (Disabled)
3. Reboot

Minifilters can't work without Filter Manager.

Comment: Hi zapador. Thanks for the suggesting this method. I played around with this and it seems like a suitable workaround. However, I was actually able to find a command that the vendor runs during the MSI uninstall that works to unload the minifilter driver. I was able to come up with a proof of concept that unloads and removes all relevant files/registry keys upon reboot. It seems to be working well so that will probably be the direction I move. Thanks again!